# Caption of figure not typeset properly

Tags: latex, caption, typesetting

I have a following kind of table structure, where my caption text refuses to be typeset properly. The normal text above it is beautifully typeset with hyphenations and spacing, but the caption looks terrible:

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={2.5cm},rmargin={2.5cm},tmargin={2.5cm},bmargin =
{2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{period-newline}{. \\}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, labelsep=period, format=plain, labelsep=period-newline, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=small}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{font=small, position=top}

\usepackage{booktabs}
 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{\textbf{Title.} \\ \smallskip \footnotesize{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     
consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dolor dui, lacinia sodales condimentum nec, 
malesuada     vel libero. Vivamus eget ipsum non lacus lacinia tincidunt sit amet eu 
metus. Fusce venenatis accumsan dui, ac commodo lorem aliquam ut. Curabitur volutpat 
urna purus. Nullam in ex sed enim feugiat ornare. Fusce sit amet auctor enim. 
Praesent nec ex eu massa feugiat tristique..}}
\centering 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lYYYYYYYYYYY}
\toprule
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\midrule
Low & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I wonder if my quite complicated caption code is causing this? Is there a better way to come up with a similar end result or can this typesetting fixed in some other way?

Comment: `justification=RaggedRight` employs an algorithm from `ragged2e` and combines left alignment with hyphenation if you want both.
`geometry` accepts an optional `margin` that applies the same value to all margins.
However, there's a bug in your code!
`\footnotesize` is a switch and does not accept inner parameter.
The braces `{}` are not doing anything while `\footnotesize` applies to the whole context.
`{\footnotesize ...}` on the other hand would apply only to an inner group.
The bug is hidden in caption because the latter forms a group, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You disable hyphenation for your captions with `justification=raggedright` in your caption setup. Either remove this entirely to get justified text for all captions or locally switch back to hyphenated text for specific captions. Same goes for the font size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={2.5cm},rmargin={2.5cm},tmargin={2.5cm},bmargin =
{2.5cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{period-newline}{. \\}
\captionsetup{labelfont={small,bf}, labelsep=period, format=plain, labelsep=period-newline, justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font=footnotesize}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{font=small, position=top}

\usepackage{booktabs}
 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}



\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     
consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dolor dui, lacinia sodales condimentum nec, 
malesuada     vel libero. Vivamus eget ipsum non lacus lacinia tincidunt sit amet eu 
metus. Fusce venenatis accumsan dui, ac commodo lorem aliquam ut. Curabitur volutpat 
urna purus. Nullam in ex sed enim feugiat ornare. Fusce sit amet auctor enim. 
Praesent nec ex eu massa feugiat tristique..

\begin{table}[h]
\caption[short version for list of tables]{{\small \textbf{Title.}\smallskip\par} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     
consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dolor dui, lacinia sodales condimentum nec, 
malesuada     vel libero. Vivamus eget ipsum non lacus lacinia tincidunt sit amet eu 
metus. Fusce venenatis accumsan dui, ac commodo lorem aliquam ut. Curabitur volutpat 
urna purus. Nullam in ex sed enim feugiat ornare. Fusce sit amet auctor enim. 
Praesent nec ex eu massa feugiat tristique..}
\centering 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lYYYYYYYYYYY}
\toprule
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
\midrule
Low & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Huge thanks, this looks great now! I used the raggedright initially to get it aligned left, so I didnt realize that was the problem. As for the text size: I want the non-bolded part to be smaller. Couldn't figure out another way to do such styling